# Overriding Devise Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Experimenting with Devise 3.0 for Rails 4 and thinking about integrating into an existing app to replace my own Authentication system.

My own `users_controller` communicated with an API (Stripe) during registration and I'm not sure how I would include this functionality if I were to use Devise?

Am I suppose to override/extend the Devise Controller in some way? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For future googlers: it is possible to call `super` in an action of inherited controller with block and do whatever you want, without overwriting Devise code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do |user|
      NotificationMailer.user_created(user).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the actions in the your controller and call `super` inside it, which will include the functionality of the corresponding devise action. And you can also add your own functionality into it.

Eg: Consider the Registrations controller ([Registrations Controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb))

Here, you can use the devise's create action code of Registration Controller in you own create action of Registration Controller and add your functionality as commented in the code.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  .
  .
  .

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        # Here the user successfully signs up, so you can use your stripe API calls here.
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks - but how do I detect if the user was signed up successfully?

Comment: So you are asking inside the create action of the Registrations controller.

Comment: Yes - in the create action, if the user is successfully created then I want to communicate with the Stripe API - I also need to update an attribute of the newly created user!

Comment: so I just extend the Devise Registration Controller and tweak their code then.

Comment: Yeah, this is repating their code in your app, but I think this is the best we can do for this situation.

Comment: Would this be automatic or would I need to tell the router to use my controller?

Comment: Please take a look at devise documentation. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers